# UPDATE, если значение изменилось, INSERT, если значения нет

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица в MySQL:

```
id  | source | source_id | time    | status | rating
----------------------------------------------------
1   | 1      | 123       | 12:10   | wait   | 1000
2   | 1      | 456       | 12:15   | done   | 2000
3   | 2      | 123       | 12:20   | wait   | 3000
```

`id` - это уникальный первичный ключ
`source` - источник откуда поступили данные
`source_id` - id данных под которым их знает источник
`time` - это `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

`source` и `source_id` не уникальны, но для конкретного source всегда уникален `source_id`

В поступающих данных имеется только `source`, `source_id`, `status`, `rating`. `rating` - постоянно меняется.

---

При данных

```
source | source_id | status | rating
-------------------------------------
1      | 123       | wait   | 55555
```

Ничего не должно произойти- штамп времени и `rating` не должны измениться, это нужно потому что при изменении штампа времени на сервере все измененные записи отправляются на клиентские машины, но `rating` абсолютно не важен, важно только изменение `status`.

---

При данных

```
source | source_id | status | rating
-------------------------------------
1      | 123       | done   | 66666
```

Должен быть выполнен `UPDATE` полей `time`, `status`, `rating`, потому что `status` изменился и нужно разослать записи клиентам.

---

При данных

```
source | source_id | status | rating
-------------------------------------
3      | 123       | done   | 77777
```

Должен быть выполнен `INSERT` новой записи.

---

Как это сделать мне подсказал @Visman в ответе ниже:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452279/481

Данное решение делает все как нужно, но в идеале хотелось бы, чтобы `UPDATE` совсем не происходил, если `status` не изменился (в указанном решении происходит `UPDATE` на те же самые значения, что уже есть на текущий момент).

Comment: Если верить [вот этому](http://stackoverflow.com/a/155061/276994), то колонка типа timestamp ведёт себя именно так, как вы описали.

Comment: А для условного добавления по идее должно сработать [это](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: @ReinRaus, вы эти действия хотите сделать одним запросом к базе?

Comment: @Visman, да, хочется  сделать это без серверного кода. VladD, да, Вы правы и это моя вина. Я думал, что привел минимальный пример, но в таблице есть еще другие поля, которые не должны быть обновлены, если статус не изменился. В этом вся суть вопроса- обновился status- обновить всю запись, статус не изменился- ничего не делать.

Comment: @VladD обновил ответ более развернуто описав все.

Comment: Я не специалист по базам, но мне кажется, что то, что вы описываете — бизнес-логика, которую скорее всего правильнее кодировать на уровне выше модели (то есть, выше базы данных). Я бы просто считал данные из таблицы, проверил их, рассчитал на основе правил, нужно ли обновление, и обновил бы, если нужно. Как-то так.

Comment: @VladD полностью согласен, можно получить текущее значение `status` и на его основе выполнить на уровне серверного кода по желаемому условию либо `INSERT` либо `UPDATE`, но это скучно же.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Согласен :) Если можно заставить работать сервер, почему бы и нет!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ делал для первого варианта вопроса, но смысл не слишком меняется и для второго, только больше переменных нужно указать.

Таблица для теста:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `time` TIMESTAMP, 
    `status` varchar(55),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO `table`
    (`id`, `time`, `status`)
VALUES
    (1, FROM_UNIXTIME(1000), 'wait'),
    (2, FROM_UNIXTIME(10000), 'success')
;
```

Наглядно

```
id  time                        status

1   January, 01 1970 00:16:40   wait
2   January, 01 1970 02:46:40   success
```

Запрос получается такой (Переменные вынесены отдельно для наглядности, хотя можно их задавать прямо в текст запроса).

1. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2d1c/1

   ```sql
   SET @id=3, @status='wait';
   insert into `table` (`id`, `time`, `status`) 
          values (@id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @status) 
          on duplicate key update `status`=@status, `time`=(
            SELECT IFNULL(`t2`.`time`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
            FROM `table` `t1` 
            LEFT JOIN `table` `t2` ON `t2`.`id`=@id AND `t2`.`status`=@status
            WHERE `t1`.`id`=@id
          );
   ```

   Получается такой результат:

   ```
   id  time                            status

   1   January, 01 1970 00:16:40       wait
   2   January, 01 1970 02:46:40       success
   3   September, 20 2015 14:07:17     done
   ```
2. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37337/1

   Переменные изменены на входе

   ```sql
   SET @id=1, @status='wait';
   ```

   Результат

   ```
   id  time                        status

   1   January, 01 1970 00:16:40   wait
   2   January, 01 1970 02:46:40   success
   ```
3. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43a82/1

   Переменные

   ```sql
   SET @id=1, @status='done';
   ```

   Результат

   ```
   id  time                            status

   1   September, 20 2015 14:08:35     done
   2   January, 01 1970 02:46:40       success
   ```

P.S. [Тут статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/156489/) про запросы вида `INSERT… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` и `AUTO_INCREMENT` и их поведение.

**UPD**

Запрос для вопроса из вашего комментария

```sql
CREATE TABLE `table` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `source` INT NOT NULL,
    `source_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `time` TIMESTAMP, 
    `status` varchar(55),
    `rating` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (`source`, `source_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table`
    (`id`, `source`, `source_id`, `time`, `status`, `rating`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 123, FROM_UNIXTIME(1000), 'wait', 1000),
    (2, 1, 456, FROM_UNIXTIME(2000), 'done', 2000),
    (3, 2, 123, FROM_UNIXTIME(3000), 'wait', 3000)
;

SET @source=1, @source_id=123, @status='wait', @rating=555;
insert into `table` (`source`, `source_id`, `time`, `status`, `rating`)
       values (@source, @source_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @status, @rating) 
       on duplicate key update `time`=(
         SELECT IFNULL(`t2`.`time`, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
         FROM `table` `t1` 
         LEFT JOIN `table` `t2` ON `t2`.`source`=@source AND `t2`.`source_id`=@source_id AND `t2`.`status`=@status
         WHERE `t1`.`source`=@source AND `t1`.`source_id`=@source_id
       ), `status`=@status, `rating`=IF(`time`<>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `rating`, @rating);
```

Тест http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/921be/1

Так как вы `id` не используете, то уникальность проверяем по паре `source` и `source_id`. `rating` и другие столбцы (если появятся) изменяем в зависимости от `time` через условие `IF(`time`<>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ...)` чтобы не плодить вложенные запросы.

Comment: Да, если у вас там не `AUTO_INCREMENT` на `id`, а уникальный ключ, то проблемы по ссылке в конце ответа у вас не будет. Чего-то я зарапортовался.

Comment: А как исправить здесь для ожидаемого результата? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eb00/1

Comment: @ReinRaus, добавил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает как хотелось. В идеале хотелось бы, чтобы `UPDATE` вообще не выполнялся, если `status` не изменился.

Comment: @ReinRaus, тут мне только приходит в голову: сначала делать SELECT и потом после проверки INSERT или UPDATE. Или ни чего не делать.